# TensorFlow: How to use 'tf.data' instead of 'load_csv_without_header'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pycharm, tensorflow-datasets

2 years ago I wrote code in TensorFlow, and as part of the data loading I used the function 'load_csv_without_header'.
Now, when I'm running the code, I get the message:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Roi\Desktop\Code_Win_Ver\code_files\Tensor_Flow\version1\build_database_tuple.py:124: load_csv_without_header (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.data instead.
```

How do I use 'tf.data' instead of the current function? How can I can the same dtype, at the same format, without the csv header with tf.data? I'm using TF version 1.8.0 over Python 3.5.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using `tf.data` to work with a `csv` file:

From TensorFlow's [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets):

> The tf.data module contains a collection of classes that allows you to easily load data, manipulate it, and pipe it into your model.

Using the API, `tf.data.Dataset` is intended as the new standard of interfacing with data in TensorFlow. It represent "a sequence of elements, in which each element contains one or more Tensor objects". For a CSV, an element is just a single row of training example, represented as a pair of tensor that correspond to the data (our `x`) and the label ("target") respectively.

Using the API, the primary method of extracting each row (or each element more accurately) in a tensorflow dataset (`tf.data.Dataset`) is by consuming the Iterator and TensorFlow has an API named `tf.data.Iterator` for that. To return the next row, we can call `get_next()` on the Iterator for example.

Now onto the code to take `csv` and transform that into our tensorflow dataset.

### Method 1: `tf.data.TextLineDataset()` and `tf.decode_csv()`

With more recent versions of TensorFlow's Estimator API, instead of `load_csv_without_header`, you'd read your CSV or using the more generic `tf.data.TextLineDataset(you_train_path)` instead. You can chain that with `skip()` to skip the first row if there is a header row, but in your case, that wasn't necessary.

You can then use `tf.decode_csv()` to pack decode each line of your CSV into its own respective fields.

The code solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf
train_path = 'data_input/iris_training.csv'
# if no header, remove .skip()
trainset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(train_path).skip(1)

# Metadata describing the text columns
COLUMNS = ['SepalLength', 'SepalWidth',
           'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth',
           'label']
FIELD_DEFAULTS = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0]]
def _parse_line(line):
    # Decode the line into its fields
    fields = tf.decode_csv(line, FIELD_DEFAULTS)

    # Pack the result into a dictionary
    features = dict(zip(COLUMNS,fields))

    # Separate the label from the features
    label = features.pop('label')

    return features, label

trainset = trainset.map(_parse_line)
print(trainset)
```

You would get:

```
<MapDataset shapes: ({
    SepalLength: (), 
    SepalWidth: (), 
    PetalLength: (), 
    PetalWidth: ()}, ()), 
types: ({
    SepalLength: tf.float32, 
    SepalWidth: tf.float32, 
    PetalLength: tf.float32, 
    PetalWidth: tf.float32}, tf.int32)>
```

You can verify the `output classes`:

```
{'PetalLength': tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor,
  'PetalWidth': tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor,
  'SepalLength': tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor,
  'SepalWidth': tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor},
 tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor)
```

You can also use `get_next` to iterate through the iterator:

```
x = trainset.make_one_shot_iterator()
x.next()
# Output:
({'PetalLength': <tf.Tensor: id=165, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.3>,
  'PetalWidth': <tf.Tensor: id=166, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.2>,
  'SepalLength': <tf.Tensor: id=167, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.4>,
  'SepalWidth': <tf.Tensor: id=168, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=3.2>},
 <tf.Tensor: id=169, shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=0>)
```

### Method 2: `from_tensor_slices()` to construct a dataset object from numpy or pandas

```
train, test = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
mnist_x, mnist_y = train

mnist_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mnist_x)
print(mnist_ds)
# returns: <TensorSliceDataset shapes: (28,28), types: tf.uint8>
```

Another (more elaborated) example:

```
import pandas as pd

california_housing_dataframe = pd.read_csv("https://download.mlcc.google.com/mledu-datasets/california_housing_train.csv", sep=",")
# Define the input feature: total_rooms
my_feature = california_housing_dataframe[["total_rooms"]]

# Configure a numeric feature column for total_rooms
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("total_rooms")]

# Define the label
targets = california_housing_dataframe["median_house_value"]

# Convert pandas data into a dict of np arrays.
features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}                                           

# Construct a dataset, and configure batching/repeating.
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features,targets))
```

---

I also strongly suggest [this article](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets_for_estimators) and [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets), both from the official documentation; Safe to say that should cover most if not all your use case and will help you migrate from the deprecated `load_csv_without_header()` function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tf.TextLineReader which has option to skip headers

```
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
```